# Using induction to prove $(ab)^n=a^n*b^n, a,b \neq 0 a,b \in \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that $(ab)^n=a^n*b^n, a,b \neq 0, a,b \in \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb Z$
I am not sure if we can use induction here.
If yes, we can see three options:
**1)** $n=0$, so $(ab)^0=1=1*1=a^0*b^0$
**2)** $n>0$, so for $n=1$ we have $(ab)^1=ab=a^1*b^1$
for $n+1$: $(ab)^{n+1}=(ab)^n*ab=a^n*a*b^n*b=a^{n+1} * b^{n+1}$
**3)** $n<0$, so here is the question. Am I allowed to use induction here?
If it is true for $-(n)$ and $-(n+1)$, does it mean that we prove whole thing using induction?
$(ab)^{-(n+1)}=(ab)^{-n}*(ab)^{-1}$=$(a^{-n}*b^{-n})/ab$=$a^{-n}*a^{-1}*b^{-n}*b^{-1}=a^{-(n+1)}*b^{-(n+1)}$

Comment: Is your group Abelian? By the way, does $*$ stand for ordinary multiplication or some binary operation? Please, provide more details. Otherwise, your question seems to relate more to abstract algebra rather than calculus

Comment: I think to do this properly you need to state at the start exactly which properties of real numbers you are allowed to assume. You also have to say what $a^{-n}$ means when $n>0$. If it means $(a^{-1})^{n}$ [ a sensible choice] then you get the negative exponent case by substituting $b^{-1}$ for $a$ and $a^{-1}$ for $b$; no need for another induction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [Mathematical Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) here. Take substitution like $a_1 = a^{-1}$ and $b_1 = b^{-1}$ if you wish. Then everything takes the form of your previous work. Note that $a,b \in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\} \implies a_1,b_1 \in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$.

---

**For the Commented Question:**

We need to prove $(a\cdot b)^p=a^p\cdot b^p$, where $p\in\mathbb Q$. Let $p = n/m$.

Then, we have $a^{n/m} = (\sqrt[m]{a})^n$ and $b^{n/m} = (\sqrt[m]{b})^n$ by definition.
$$(a\cdot b)^{n/m}=(\sqrt[m]a \cdot\sqrt[m]b)^n$$
By taking $c = \sqrt[m]a$ and $d=\sqrt[m]b$, we see that, again, it comes down to your previous work.

Comment: Thanks. And what about proving the same thing, but in case $a,b>0,n\in\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @BorisVedernikov The difficulty is again stating exactly what $a^{n}$ means when $n\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @BorisVedernikov See my addition.

Comment: @BorisVedernikov Does this answer satisfy you now?

Comment: @VIVID Yeah sure, I am on my third week of B.Sc in math so still haven’t got used to proving everything...

Answer (score 1):

$$(ab)^{n+1}=a(ba)^nb\overset{?}=a(ab)^nb\overset{*}=a(a^nb^n)b=a^{n+1}b^{n+1}$$

The step (?) works uses the commutativity of $\Bbb R$ under the operation of multiplication which suggests that we need an abelian group for the general result to hold.

The step (*) is applying the inductive hypothesis.